# Returning an Associative array from admin-post.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a form (below) that runs a couple of PHP functions on submission and generates an array of URLs and their statuses, however I can't get the array back from $_POST and trying to save it as a transient only gave me the last line, any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
Form code
echo "<form action=".admin_url('admin-post.php')." method='post'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='action' value='sisb_spider_start'>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Run Link Checker'>";
echo "</form>";



echoing on admin-post.php
foreach($output as $url=>$result){
  if($result=="1"){
  echo "<p style='color:red'>".$url." is not responding, Please fix this and try again.</br></p>";
}
  elseif($result=="2"){
    echo "<p style='color:green'>".$url." is responding.</br></p>";
  }
}

result from echoing on admin-post.php

http://sisb.test is responding.

http://sisb.test/page-2/ is responding.

http://sisb.test/ is responding.

http://sisb.test/nonexistant is not responding, Please fix this and try again.

http://sisb.test/sample-page is responding.

http://sisb.test/page-2 is responding.

http://sisb.test/wp-admin/ is responding.

http://sisb.test/hello-world/ is responding.

http://sisb.test/hello-world/#comment-1 is responding.

http://sisb.test/category/uncategorized/ is responding.

http://sisb.test/wp-login.php is responding.

http://sisb.test/feed/ is responding.

http://sisb.test/comments/feed/ is responding.
```

Comment: "however I can't get the array back from $_POST" you're not submitting anything to the form other than the input 'action' value.

Comment: It is unclear to me what your goal, expected result and actual result are ;(
don't you already have an associative array in the $output variable?

Comment: sorry if i wasnt too clear, i have the array available on admin-post.php as $output but I can't work out how I should be saving or returning this to be used on other pages (ideally a page that the form to start the function is on)

Comment: @PhilipRollins figured that might be the case, is there a better way to get the data from admin-post.php to other parts of the plugin?

Comment: I would first look to store it in the session object if applicable (browser session only) but if needed in the backend (or across sessions) a simple (SQLite database/JSON file) holding the responding boolean `url[string]: isResponsing[bool]` would be my goto